# Returning a void?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, return, void

I do not understand why this code compiles without error:

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
struct Test
{
    static constexpr T f() {return T();} 
};

int main()
{
    Test<void> test;
    test.f(); // Why not an error?
    return 0;
}
```

Is it ok according to the standard, or is it a compiler tolerance?

Comment: Well, I know you're allowed to have, say, `void foo() {} void bar() {return foo();}`. I'm not sure about this.

Comment: What is your question about, specifically? About returning `void` (which, BTW, has always been legal in C++)? Or about `constexpr void` combination?

Comment: Maybe you should explain what you think the error should be?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This looks valid by the [draft C++11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf), if we look at section `5.2.3` *Explicit type conversion (functional notation)* paragraph *2* says (*emphasis mine*):

> The **expression T()**, where T is a simple-type-specifier or
>   typename-specifier for a non-array complete object type **or the
>   (possibly cv-qualified) void type**, creates a prvalue of the
>   specified type, whose value is that produced by value-initializing
>   (8.5) an object of type T; no initialization is done for the void()
>   case.[...]

the wording is pretty similar [pre C++11](http://www.open-std.org/Jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1804.pdf) as well.

This okay in a *constexpr* even though section `7.1.5` paragraph `3` says:

> The definition of a constexpr function shall satisfy the following
>   constraints:

and includes this bullet:

> its return type shall be a literal type;

and *void* is not a *literal* in *C++11* as per section `3.9` paragraph *10*, *but* if we then look at paragraph *6* it gives an exception that fits this case, it says:

> If the instantiated template specialization of a constexpr function
>   template or member function of a class template would fail to satisfy
>   the requirements for a constexpr function or constexpr constructor,
>   that specialization is not a constexpr function or constexpr
>   constructor. [ Note: If the function is a member function it will
>   still be const as described below. —end note ] **If no specialization of
>   the template would yield a constexpr function or constexpr
>   constructor, the program is ill-formed; no diagnostic required**.

As Casey [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20478193/returning-a-void#comment30604069_20478435) in the [C++14 draft standard](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/master/papers/n4140.pdf) *void* is a *literal*, this is section `3.9` *Types* paragraph *10* says:

> A type is a literal type if it is:

and includes:

> — void; or

Answer (score 6):

See @Shafik Yaghmour's answer for the full info.

The following paragraph forbids this for non-templates (7.1.5(3)):

> The definition of a `constexpr` function shall satisfy the following constraints:
>
> - [...]
> - its return type shall be a literal type or a reference to literal type

To elaborate, a literal type is defined in 3.9(10) as a scalar type or a composition of literal type objects in an array or struct. `void` is not a scalar type by 3.9(9).

Comment: *literal type* is defined in 3.9/10; `void` is *not* a literal type in C++11. In C++14 (N3797) however, `void` *is* included in the literal types. So the OP's code will be conforming to C++14.

Comment: @Casey Also I think 7.1.5 paragraph 6 allows for this in C++11

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Ahh, I agree. Interesting: this code specializes to a non-`constexpr` but `const` member function in C++11, or a `constexpr` and non-`const` member function in C++14!

Comment: @Casey That would be correct if the declaration was for a non-`static` member function, but the OP has a `static` member so it won't be `const` in any case. Please pay attention, idiot!

Answer (score 1):

Your function returns the value of `void()`, you are not returning from a void function per se. You are returning a `NULL` value. What you are doing is equivalent to this:

```
void f() { return void(); }
```

This returns a void value, the only void value. you can't return anything else from a void function because it will be of a different type.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this is allowed in C++ by 5.2.3(2), though IANALL.

Comment: It is allowed by the compiler, but it isn't really useful as it has no value whatsoever.

Comment: This is not the point when talking about a language standard.

Comment: @user3084096 it could be useful as a parameterized type in a template, returning the default constructed element. It might avoid special cases.