# Void as a literal type?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

In C++14 `void` is a literal type

> A type is a literal type if it is:
>
> — void; or
>
> — a scalar type; or
>
> — a reference type; or
>
> — an array of literal type; or
>
> — a class type (Clause 9) that has all of the following properties: —
>   it has a trivial destructor,
>
> — it is an aggregate type (8.5.1) or has at least one constexpr
>   constructor or constructor template that is not a copy or move
>   constructor, and
>
> — all of its non-static data members and base classes are of
>   non-volatile literal types.

In C++11 `void` is not a literal type

> A type is a literal type if it is:
>
> — a scalar type; or
>
> — a reference type referring to a literal type; or
>
> — an array of literal type; or
>
> — a class type (Clause 9) that has all of the following properties: —
>   it has a trivial destructor,
>
> — every constructor call and full-expression in the
>   brace-or-equal-initializers for non-static data members (if any) is a
>   constant expression (5.19),
>
> — it is an aggregate type (8.5.1) or has at least one constexpr
>   constructor or constructor template that is not a copy or move
>   constructor, and
>
> — all of its non-static data members and base classes are of literal
>   types.

So why is `void` a literal type? What benefits does it offer?

Comment: Related to [Returning a void?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20478193/1708801)

Answer (score 18):

Since `void` is `literal type`, `constexpr` functions can have return type `void` in C++14.

[It's covered in this proposal.](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3444.html)

Quote from proposal:

> An arbitrary expression-statement is permitted, in order to allow
>   calls to functions performing checks and to allow assert-like
>   constructs. **void also becomes a literal type, so that constexpr
>   functions which exist only to perform such checks may return void.**

```
#define ASSERT(expr) \
  (void)((expr) || assert_failed(#expr, __LINE__, __FILE__))
void assert_failed(...); // not constexpr
struct S {
  std::array a<int, 100>;
  size_t i;

  constexpr void check_invariants() const {
    ASSERT(i < a.size());
    ASSERT(a[i] == 0);
  }
  S(std::array<int, 100> a_, size_t i_) : a(a_), i(i_) {
    check_invariants();
  }
};
```

Comment: In C++14, can a `void` variable be declared/returned? Obviously it is not inherently useful and cannot be accessed but for generic/templated code it could sometimes simplify things.