# constexpr void function rejected

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++14, return-type, constexpr

I have this very simple function which won't compile.

```
constexpr void func()
{
}
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
error: invalid return type 'void' of constexpr function 'constexpr void func()'

     constexpr void func()
```

In C++14, `void` is a literal type [§3.9/10]:

> A type is a *literal type* if it is:
>
> - void; or
> - a scalar type; or
> - a reference type; or
> - an array of literal type; or
> - a class type (Clause 9) that has all of the following properties:
>
>   - it has a trivial destructor,
>   - it is an aggregate type (8.5.1) or has at least one `constexpr` constructor or constructor template that is not a copy or move constructor, and
>   - all of its non-static data members and base classes are of non-volatile literal types.

Can someone explain why this is invalid?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Void as a literal type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27486581/void-as-a-literal-type)

Comment: Citing a working draft post-C++14 isn't very useful for proving facts about C++14.

Answer (score 10):

The proposal which made `void` a literal type was [**n3652 Relaxing constraints on `constexpr` functions**](http://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3652.html). G++ decided to push this feature to version [5](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-5/changes.html#cxx) (I was using 4.9.2):

> G++ now supports C++14 extended constexpr.
>
> ```
> constexpr int f (int i)
> {
>   int j = 0;
>   for (; i > 0; --i)
>     ++j;
>   return j;
> }
>
> constexpr int i = f(42); // i is 42
> ```

Clang has had this implemented since version 3.4.

Answer (score 7):

It is valid indeed, but not yet supported in GCC. An example in the standard actually includes `constexpr` functions returning `void` - see [dcl.constexpr]/1:

```
constexpr void square(int &x); // OK: declaration
 // [..]
constexpr void square(int &x) { // OK: definition
    x *= x;
}
```

[Example on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c41e6a4e10a12af5) using Clang, which is conforming here.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from *The C++ Programmig Language (4th Edition)*:

> A constexpr function may not have side-effects.

So, what would be the purpose of a constexpr void function?

If you are aiming to do something like that:

```
constexpr void Twice(int &a)
{
    a *= 2;
}
```

You should consider changing to:

```
constexpr int Twice(int a)
{
    return 2 * a;
}
```

Comment: Purpose? Easy, e.g.: template<typename T> constexpr void requireIntegral() { static_assert(std::is_integral<T>::value, "type must be integral"); };

Comment: You're right, good point. Never thought of using constexpr functions that way.