# Understanding void constexpr-functions in c++14

Tags: c++, c++14, constexpr

Since C++14 constexpr-functions can return `void`. What is the point in using void constexpr-functions, because they can't make any side-effects?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29261434/707111, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29261276/constexpr-void-function-rejected#comment51547488_29262339

Comment: `constexpr` member functions can mutate state