# Avoiding special case for `void` return types for functionals

Tags: c++

When writing a function template that should return whatever a passed functional returns -- how can I avoid the fact that the `return` statement cannot be used with a function returning `void`?

Example:

```
struct FunctionalVoid {
    typedef void result_type;
    result_type foo () const { return; }
};

struct FunctionalInt {
    typedef int result_type;
    result_type foo () const { return 42; }
};

template< class F >
typename F::result_type
g (const F & f) {
   return f.foo ();
}
```

Now I can write `g (FunctionalInt {});`, yet I cannot write `g (FunctionalVoid {});`. Is there any way to solve this problem without writing `g` twice?

(A real `g` would, of course, be a more complicated function.)

(Edit: Stupidity reduced -- member function called `foo` instead of `do`.)

Comment: You are allowed to return a `void` expression from a `void` function. What error did you get when you tried? (And perhaps you can post the code you actually tested, without extra errors like trying to name a function `do`).

Comment: And by that, jrok doesn't mean your 5,000 line project. He means the MCVE you constructed to debug this. It's extremely similar to the code above, except not broken, and has a `main` function.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20478193/560648

Comment: Hm, that's embarrassing. I completely mis-interpreted the error message '''Void function' cannot return a value". (Well, if I think about this error message twice, its statement is not correct.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You don't need to!**

`return void()` is *valid* (in a function returning `void`), allowing precisely this.

What you're *not* allowed to do is to name a function `do`, as that is a keyword.

So, when I rename `do` to `foo` and add the following `main` function, [the only diagnostics emitted by my compiler are warnings about an unused variable](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/db5f243ddc5fb6ed):

```
int main()
{
    FunctionalVoid obj1;
    g(obj1);

    FunctionalInt obj2;
    int result2 = g(obj2);
}
```