# Status of statement (void)f() in C++14, is it ill-formed? if not, is the f() part discard-value?

Tags: c++, c++14

Is the following program ill-formed according to the C++14 standard?

```
int f() { return 42; }

int main() {
  (void)f();
}
```

If not, is the sole function call expression contained within a discard-value expression?  (note that is the subexpression, not the whole expression statement)

Comment: Do you have any references that make you think `(void)f()` is ill-formed?

Comment: @RSahu: Well void is an incomplete type so:  `void t = f();` is ill-formed, I would therefore expect `(void)x` to mean (without wording to the contrary) create a temporary of type void, which is equivalent to the ill-formed `void t = f();` previously mentioned.  However in C this is well-formed, so I'm unclear.

Comment: @AndrewTomazos `void t` would not be a temporary (if it were legal). `void` is a valid type for an expression. For example a call to a void function.

Comment: You also see code like `(void)param;` to silence sometimes bogus warnings about un-used parameter `param` in a function, so the expression is definitely valid C++.

Comment: Also see [Returning a void?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20478193/1708801)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is the following program ill-formed according to the C++14 standard?

No. If you have some specific reason for thinking this might be invalid, you might be able to get a more detailed answer, but quoting each and every sentence of the standard in an attempt to point out that that sentence doesn't render the program invalid is not productive.

> If not, is the sole function call expression contained within a discard-value expression?

The sole function call expression *is* the discarded-value expression.

> **5.2.9 Static cast [expr.static.cast]**
>
> 6 Any expression can be explicitly converted to type *cv* `void`, in which case it becomes a discarded-value expression (Clause 5). [...]

I am assuming you are already aware that a C-style cast performs a `static_cast` if possible.

Comment: `[expr.static.cast]/6` is what I was after.  Thanks for your help.